# Efficient way to modify every cell in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a python project and got a dataframe with multiple columns and rows.

I would like to get rid of everything but the digits in every cell of the dataframe.
Is it possible to do this without using loops?

Here is a sample from the data:

```
         a       b       c       d       e       f        g      h   
1    att-7   att-3  att-10  att-10   att-15  att-11    att-2  att-7  
2    att-9   att-7  att-12   att-4   att-10   att-4   att-13  att-4  
3   att-10   att-6   att-1   att-1   att-13  att-12    att-9  att-6
```

I would like to apply somehting like this:

```
def modify_string(cell):
    return cell.str.extract(r'(\d+)')

df_modified = df.apply(lambda x: modify_string(x))
```

Is it possible to avoid loops here? What would be the most efficient way since the data is relatively big? How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way using `applymap` will apply the function elementwise. It relies on the numbers being followed by a '-'.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('-')[-1])
```

If this is not always the case, you could also use `str.extract` and extract the numbers.

```
df.stack().str.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False).unstack()
```

Output:

```
    a  b   c   d   e   f   g  h
1   7  3  10  10  15  11   2  7
2   9  7  12   4  10   4  13  4
3  10  6   1   1  13  12   9  6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use: https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/ and simple apply function.

Answer (score -1):

```
df1
df2 = df1.astype('str').replace('att-', '', regex=True)
df2
```

**Update**: if you need to use values as numbers after that just add the following

```
df2 = df2.astype('int64')
```

| index | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 3 | 10 | 10 | 15 | 11 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 9 | 7 | 12 | 4 | 10 | 4 | 13 | 4 |
| 3 | 10 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 13 | 12 | 9 | 6 |